# Centered, Fluid UL with Bullets

Tags: html, css

We've got an odd request from a client. They want a particular `<ul>`'s content to be centered with the icons. Centering isn't a problem in and of itself, neither are the icons.

The issue is that I can't find a way to center the `<li>`s at a variable width without the icon being left aligned.

So we're trying to achieve something like you see in http://jsfiddle.net/MBEKW/, with the exception that the icons should float normally to the left of the `<li>`, as it would if it were left-aligned.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? FWIW, we are using TWBS 2.1.1, but this seems so vanilla that bootstrap shouldn't even be a factor.

Comment: try centering the entire div intead of just the <ul>

Comment: The issue is the `li`s, not the `ul` itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this

```
li {
    border: 1px dotted green;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBEKW/2/)

OR you can do the image icon like this

http://jsfiddle.net/MBEKW/3/